# ASP.net MVC Unobtrusive Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I'm having trouble validating a form before sending the input to an Azure Logic App. On clicking the submit button in the view, form contents are submitted without validation. Validation does fire but the form is submitted whether valid or not. Can anyone help?

Model...

```
    public class Contact
{
    [DisplayName("Name:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Phone:")]
    [MaxLength(15)]
    [MinLength(8)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[0-9]*$", ErrorMessage = "Phone number can only contain numbers.")]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Message:")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a message.")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("newsletterTextbox")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your email address.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\S+@\S+\.\S+$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid email address.")]
    public string newsletterTextbox { get; set; }
}
```

View...

```
<div class="col-md-8 col-md-push-1">
            <!-- CONTACT FORM -->
            <div id="contactDiv" class="contact-form">
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name, new { placeholder = "Name", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name, "", new { @style = "color: Orange" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { placeholder = "Email", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Email, "", new { @style = "color: Orange" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { placeholder = "Phone", @class = "form-control" })
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Message, new { placeholder = "Message", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Message, "", new { @style = "color: Orange" })
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="submit" onclick="contactSubmit()" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-center float-right">Submit your message</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- / CONTACT FORM -->
        </div>
```

js...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/superagent/2.2.0/superagent.min.js"></script>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery");
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval");

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var frm = $("#contactForm");
    frm.validate();
});

function contactSubmit() {
    var f = $("#contactForm");
    if (f.valid()) {
        superagent
            .post(*** Azure Logic App URL ***)
            .send({
                name: document.getElementById('Name').value,
                email: document.getElementById('Email').value,
                phone: document.getElementById('Phone').value,
                message: document.getElementById('Message').value
            })
            .end(function (err, res) {
                if (err || !res.ok) {
                    alert('Whoops. Something went wrong.');
                } else {
                    var div = document.getElementById('contactDiv');
                    var successText = document.getElementById('contactText');
                    div.style.display = "none";
                    successText.Text = "Thanks! We'll be in touch";
                    successText.innerHTML = "Thanks! We'll be in touch";
                    successText.value = "Thanks! We'll be in touch";
                }
            });
        return false;
    }

    else {
        return false;
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: Remove your `var frm = $("#contactForm"); frm.validate();` - that is already done by the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` plugin. The `if (f.valid()) {` is correct and the ajax call will not be made if the form is invalid. If its not working it is due to something you have not shown. Are you sure the scripts are being loaded correctly, and in the correct order?

Comment: Change the button type to button.

Comment: Thank you. These two answers combined did the trick!

Comment: @weser, The button should **not** be changed to `type="button"`

Comment: But what you should be doing is deleting the `onclick="contactSubmit()"` and using `$('#contactForm').submit(function() {` instead of `function contactSubmit() {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your form with

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", new { Controller = "ControllerName", area = "" }, new AjaxOptions() { OnSuccess = "onSuccessFunction", HttpMethod = "POST", UpdateTargetId = "idtobeupdated"}, new { id = "idofform" }))
```

and don´t use javascript / jquery.

You need to install Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation and *.Ajax for this.